Azurite in docker response 403 when i trying to access through to web browser
When I try to access the Azurite blob using edge I meet the error like this - the logs of docker container:
https://i.sstatic.net/F7QEWnVo.png
But I still can upload a file from my blob service in .NET Core.
My code:
https://i.sstatic.net/Lzw0RNdr.png
Postman return ok and my database has this url:
https://i.sstatic.net/oJzrQNnA.png
I don't know how to fix that, I have tried to set blob to 0.0.0.0 but it still returns this error

Error 403 is forbidden which usually means you do not have access to the Route.  Get the http headers in Postman using the Postman Control panel.  Then add missing headers to you c# code.  Postman will automatically add http headers to the request while c# libraries do not add the headers.

I try to access to Azurite through the browser not in the c# code, is there anyway to do it?, i read the docs and in tell me just access normally but i can't :((

Browser doesn't automatically add the same headers as Postman.  You have to look at the Postman Control Panel and get the entire Request.  The Postman  request will headers like Authorization.  You may be using the wrong Authorization mode.  User Agent may be the reason for the error.  Some servers do not allow all browsers and the User Agent is used to tell what browser is being used.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Have you included the access key in your request?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio%2Cblob-storage#connection-strings
